# Android Error: Out of memory

Tags: android, html, out-of-memory

I used HTML to show pictures in TextView, the following codes are to load pictures. Now I have an error named "out of memory".

I think the reason is that I did not free the memory in Destory() of that activity, but how can I free them?

Please help, thanks!

```
final Html.ImageGetter imageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(source);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 400,500);//drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        return drawable;
    }
};

tv_show.setText(Html.fromHtml(html.toString(), imageGetter, null));
```

Comment: Maybe the source image is too large, you can try lowering the size and quality of the source image just to verify. Using image loading libraries like Glide, Universal Image Loader, and such are recommended.

Comment: what does drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()) return?

Comment: @razzledazzle,Thanks for your help first,I know the reason is the image is too large,but I can not change the size and quality ,they are what I need.now ,I want to ask you for " if I have an object of Drawable,how can I free it after having used it",thanks.

Comment: @MarkRenouf,Sorry,I don't know.But when i use them,my pictures will be so big to be cut.